# $ 0 \le f(x) \le 1 $ for $ 0 \lt x < 1 \implies \int_0^x f(t)t ~dt \le x^2 $ for all $ x\in(0,1) $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the following implication, and I need to determine whether it's true:

$ 0 \le f(x) \le 1 $ for $ 0 \lt x < 1 \implies \int_0^x f(t)t ~dt \le x^2 $ for all $ x\in(0,1) $

I tried solving this by doing the following:

$$  \int_0^x f(t)t ~dt \le x^2 \iff D \int_0^x f(t)t ~dt \le D x^2 \iff f(x)x \le 2x \iff f(x)\le 2 $$

Ergo, $ 0 \le f(x) \le 1 $ for $ 0 \lt x < 1 $ does not imply that $ \int_0^x f(t)t ~dt \le x^2 $ for all $ x\in(0,1) $

Edit: I see what I did wrong. Still trying to digest the proof.

Comment: I think you are applying differentiation $D$ in your proof, but in general $a(x) \geq b(x)$ does not imply $\frac{da}{dx} \geq \frac{db}{dx}$. Take $a(x) = 1/x$ and $b(x)= -1/x$ for example.

Comment: @John thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)\in(0,1]$ then
$$0\leq\int_{0}^{x} f(t)t\,dt \leq \int_{0}^{x}t\,dt = \frac{x^2}{2}\leq x^2,$$
so the inequality is true.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing out on something here, but is the implication true? If so, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @user1904218: What you did is to prove that the inequality still holds if we replace the condition $f(x)\in(0,1]$ with the weaker condition $f(x)\leq 2$.

Comment: Forgive me if this is silly, but I'm not trying to prove the inequality. I'm trying to determine whether the implication is true. Does the inequality being true also mean that the implication is true?

Comment: @user1904218: The implication is true, and this answer gives you a proof.

Comment: @John Ok, thanks. This is over my head right now, need to digest it.

Comment: I'm really struggling with the proof. Could you perhaps dumb it down a notch? And maybe explain the steps involved? For example, how do you determine that $0\leq\int_{0}^{x} f(t)t\,dt $?

Comment: The integral of a non-negative integrable function is non-negative.